# Unreal Engine 4 "project coult not be compiled"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I have downloaded UE4 recently and cant get a C++ class to open. As I create the project this shows up:

```
Running C:/Program Files (x86)/Epic Games/4.10/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe MyProject6 Development Win64 -project="C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject6/MyProject6.uproject" -rocket -editorrecompile -progress -noubtmakefiles -2015
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject6Editor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool "C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/Unreal Projects/MyProject6/MyProject6.uproject" "C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject6\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject6Editor\Development\UnrealHeaderTool.manifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -rocket -installed
Reflection code generated for MyProject6Editor in 11,6497437 seconds
@progress pop
Performing 7 actions (4 in parallel)
[2/7] Resource PCLaunch.rc
[3/7] Resource ModuleVersionResource.rc.inl
PCH.MyProject6.h.cpp
MyProject6.cpp
MyProject6GameMode.cpp
MyProject6.generated.cpp
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject6\Source\MyProject6\MyProject6GameMode.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled headerC:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject6\Source\MyProject6\MyProject6.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled header

C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject6\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Inc\MyProject6\MyProject6.generated.cpp: error C4599: '/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE': command line argument number 228 does not match precompiled header
-------- End Detailed Actions Stats -----------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Unreal Projects\MyProject6\Binaries\Win64\UE4Editor-MyProject6.dll
Total build time: 100,66 seconds
```

Any ideas what went wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you found the line in the log and determined which token is arg 228?

Answer (score 0):

Your game mode sourcefile is including a header that is incorrect in some way. I see a reference to line 228 but I'm unsure if that's in your game mode or in an included header.